# is this quadratic form positive semi-definite?

Tags: linear-algebra

Quadratic form in 3-dimensional space is given as

$$Q(x) =  ax_1^2 + 5x_2^2 + x_3^2 +7x_1x_2 +4x_2x_3$$

The question is what is the minimum possible value that parameter $a$ can take that form is positive sem-definite.

I solved it as follows:

$$ax_1^2 + 5x_2^2 + x_3^2 +7x_1x_2 +4x_2x_3 = ax_1^2 +2*3.5x_1x_2 + x_2^2  + (2x_2 + x_3)^2$$

As we can see $a$ need to be equal to $3.5^2$

Is my solution correct or I need to form the matrix of quadratic form and find when it is positive semi-definite?

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Comment: The $Q$ in the question contains the cross term $4x_1x_3$ but in your work, it becomes $4x_2x_3$.

Comment: @user1551  it should be $x_2x_3$, sorry for typo

Comment: Then I have to modify my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct but your reasoning isn't clear. You have shown that $Q\succeq0$ when $a=3.5^2$, but you haven't shown why any smaller $a$ isn't possible.

A more systematic way to solve the problem is to obtain the matrix representation of $Q$ and make use of [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) for positive semidefinite matrices. In your case, the matrix representation is given by
$$
Q=\pmatrix{a&7/2&0\\ 7/2&5&2\\ 0&2&1}.
$$
By Sylvester's criterion, $Q\succeq0$ if and only if all principal minors of $Q$ are nonnegative. This means we need
$$
a,5,1,\begin{vmatrix}a&7/2\\ 7/2&5\end{vmatrix},
\begin{vmatrix}a&0\\ 0&1\end{vmatrix},
\begin{vmatrix}5&2\\ 2&1\end{vmatrix},
\begin{vmatrix}a&7/2&0\\ 7/2&5&2\\ 0&2&1\end{vmatrix}\ge0,
$$
i.e.
$$
a,\ 5a-\frac{49}{4},\ a-\frac{49}{4}\ge0.
$$
Hence the least feasible $a$ is $\frac{49}{4}$.